# FosRestBundle. How to return full response on redirect

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

When I post data to server redirect happens:

```php
$view = $this->routeRedirectView('get_config', array('id' => $config->getId()));
return $this->handleView($view);
```

Here is a code of action where request is being redirected to:

```php
/** 
 * @View()
 */
public function getConfigAction($id)
{   
    $config = $this->getConfigById($id);
    return array('configs' => array($config));
}
```

Creation works correctly. However redirect is not working as I would want it to work. When I execute the following command

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \
-d '{"config": {"name": "TEST1"}}' http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/configs
```

The output is:

```
< HTTP/1.0 201 Created
< Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 14:13:17 GMT
< location: http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/configs/12
```

I can't manage the response to contain newly created entity. Here is desired output:

```
< HTTP/1.0 201 Created
< Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 14:13:17 GMT
< location: http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/configs/12
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <entry>
    <entry>
      <id>12</id>
      <name><![CDATA[TEST1]]></name>
    </entry>
  </entry>
</result>
```

Comment: Why provide a location header if the content il already there ? A client getting a 201 with a location header will probably just follow the location.

Comment: @AdrienBrault, I thought rest approach requires setting location for responses of PUT and POST operations. No?

Comment: Yep, that's why I don't understand why you also include the representation along with the location.

Comment: @AdrienBrault, otherwise I would have to make additional request to load this data via GET. I thought it was possible to avoid extra request. But I quess it's not possible, right?

Comment: If you set the Location header, the client should make an extra request and follow the link.
If you want to avoid extra requests, just return the representation without setting the Location header!

Comment: @AdrienBrault, thank you. That makes sense. I just thought that not setting `location` would contradict to REST approach. Apparently it wouldn't. You might want to post your response as an answer and I will accept it.